# Redirect all users to dashboard unless custom post type

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect any visitors to the dashboard unless they land on a specific custom post type (fruits).

So the following URLs would all redirect to the dashboard...

```
https://www.example.com/contact
https://www.example.com/sales
https://www.example.com/blog
```

But the following would work as usual..

```
https://www.example.com/fruits/apple
https://www.example.com/fruits/grape
https://www.example.com/fruits/banana
```

I have this so far...

```
function redirect_to_backend() {
    if (!is_singular( 'fruits' )) {
         wp_redirect( admin_url(), 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_to_backend' );
```

But this is not working, anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest hook that `is_singular()` will work on is `wp`.  replace `init` with `wp` in your `add_action` call

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue :)